# MVC Identity - User Overview with AspNetUser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, user-registration

I'm new to MVC Identity and have a problem.

I want to implement a User overview for the admin, where he can edit/delete them. I use MVC identity for Registration and Login, so registered users are saved in the aspnet tables in the db. But I have an own table for the user with other attributes (like name, address etc.).

So my question is: Can I save the registered users in my own user table? Or can I add the attributes/columns of the users to the aspnetuser table and show them in the overview?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of adding a new table for the additional properties you could simply extend the built-in ApplicationUser class by adding properties in `Project > Models > IdentityModels.cs > ApplicationUser`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   // these are additional properties
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string MiddleName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

2. Then after the step above, add a migration to update the Users table by going to Nuget Package Manager Console and typing `add-migration "migration name here"`.
3. After adding a migration, on the same Nuget Package Manager Console, run `Update-Database`, this will run your migrations.
4. Add a controller action that will return the users.

```
public ActionResult ViewUsers(){
   return View(db.Users.ToList());
}
```

5. Add a view named `ViewUsers.cshtml` with the code below.

```
@model List<ApplicationUser>

<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
      @foreach(var item in model){
         <tr>
            <td>@item.Email</td>
            <td>@item.LastName , @item.FirstName</td>
         </tr>
      }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try to add-migraton, I get the following error "The project failed to build". Any idea?

Comment: @JoeJackson try to rebuild the project first, right click solution > rebuild, then it will show you the errors. Let me know what the errors are

Comment: I get "The Type or Namespace name could not be found" errors. My target framework is 4.7.2

Comment: Oh, on the view, try this line instead; `@model List<ProjectName.Models.ApplicationUser>` replace ProjectName with your Project Name